# Finding a sequence of step functions converging uniformly to $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty 2^{-n}\mathbb{1}(x>q^n)$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series, solution-verification

As I was revising my Real Analysis course, I came across this strange problem on series of functions. If anybody can verify that the first and last parts of the proof are correct and give me hints about the second part, it will be greatly appreciated.

> Let $f\colon[0,1]\to\mathbb R$ be the function defined by $$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty 2^{-n}\mathbb{1}(x>q^n),$$ where $q=1/3$. Recall that for $a\in\mathbb R$, $\mathbb 1(\cdot>a)$ is the indicator function of the interval $(a,\infty)\subset \mathbb R$; that is $\mathbb 1(x>a)=1$ if $x\in(a,\infty)$ and zero otherwise.
>
> 1. Verify that $f$ is well-defined at every point of $[0,1]$ and sketch its graph, marking the points $(0,f(0))$, $(1,f(1))$, $(q,f(q))$.
> 2. Construct a sequence of step functions $\varphi_n\colon[0,1]\to\mathbb R$ converging uniformly to $f$. Hence, calculate $\int_0^1 f$.

For the first part, we simply note that for any $x\in[0,1]$ we have $|2^{-n}\mathbb 1(x>q^n)|\leqslant 2^{-n}$. Now, $\sum_{n=0}^\infty 2^{-n}=2$, being a geometric series, and so $\sum_{n=0}^\infty 2^{-n}\mathbb{1}(x>q^n)<2$ for all $x$. The infinite series converges uniformly by the Weierstrass M-test (with $M_n=2^{-n}$), for all $x\in[0,1]$. Therefore, $f$ is well-defined on $[0,1]$. We graph $f$ by noting that $f(1)=2-2^0$, $f(q)=2-2^0-2^{-1}=1/2$, and $f(0)=0$.

[image: Figure 1]

Now, I cannot really see what this sequence of step functions is going to be, but I think I can calculate the integral nonetheless; for each $n$, we want to find the area of the rectangles with width $(3^{-n}-3^{-n+1})$ and height $2^{-n+1}$. So, $$\int_0^1 f=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac12\right)^{n-1}\left(\frac1{3^{n-1}} -\frac1{3^n}\right)=\frac{2}{3}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{6^{n-1}}=\frac45.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 1., your argument is correct.

For 2., I think the wanted sequence of step functions is given by 
$$\varphi_N(x)=\sum_{n=1}^N2^{-n}\mathbf 1\left\{x>q^n\right\}.$$
Notice that for each $x$, $|f(x)-\varphi_N(x)|\leqslant \sum_{n\geqslant N+1}2^{-n}$, which proves the uniform convergence. Then $\int_0^1f=\lim_n\int_0^1\varphi_n$, and this limit is computed in your attempt.